# This isn't a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Can my question:

[Why did Palpatine care about Anakin Skywalker in the Prequels given Palpatine's pretty good Force Vision?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65407/31519)

be unmarked as a duplicate?

It has nothing to do with:

[Why did Palpatine save Vader](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64436/31519)

The latter deals with the Sith code of ethics, and the strong ignoring the weak, and effectively asks "why would one Sith help another, junior Sith". It is an interesting question.

My question asks why Palpatine bothered with Vader, given both Vader's uselessness to the overall story arc (aside from killing Palpatine) and Palpatine's ability to see the future.
It also (implicitly) inquires why Palpatine, who is solely responsible for everything that happens in the prequels, even bothered with an apprentice at all.

The questions are different, and while they're both good questions, that's not a reason to mark them as duplicates.

Comment: I didn't mark it as a duplicate but they seem pretty darn duplicate-y to me.

Comment: @Richard I just don't see it. One is "why did Palpatine choose Anakin as his apprentice?"  The other is "why did Palpatine not give up on Vader after he was critically wounded?"

Comment: @beofett - "Why did he pick Anakin" also seems to cover "why did he stick with Anakin"

Comment: @Richard Given that Sith historically abhor weakness, and the general philosophy seems to be that only the victors deserve to live, and mercy is a weakness that is not worthy of a Sith, the two strike me as suitably distinct.  We'll just have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: @Beofett - I didn't vote to close it, but I won't be voting to open it either.

Comment: @Richard Fair enough.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from the Help Centre on [duplicate questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) (emphasis mine):

> If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, **edit it to highlight the differences**, or try to get it reopened by casting a reopen vote or flagging it for moderator attention.

Posting on Meta is fine, but I think you should also edit the question. Here’s why:

1. **More likely to get reopen votes.**

   Users with >3k rep have access to a “Reopen queue”, where they review questions that have been closed and nominated for reopening. They may not see the Meta discussion, but they will notice edits to the original question.

   Editing the question within five days of closure bumps it into this queue, although I see that the question already has one reopen vote, so it’s already in the queue.

   Explaining in the question why this isn’t a duplicate is more likely to get you reopen votes from anybody going through this queue.
2. **Less likely to be closed again.**

   It’s unusual for questions to be repeatedly closed and reopened, but sometimes a closed-and-reopened question will attract a few stray close votes. If the question specifically addresses the proposed duplicate, then that’s much less likely to happen.

Comment: so what, would i edit the question with a disclaimer at the top of the page? doesn't that detract from the question itself?

Comment: @bharal Normally it's put at the bottom of the question body, just above the comments.